# rpm command doesn't show the package config file

Tags: apache-httpd, rpm

rpm -qc httpd doesn't show all of the httpd config files.My OS is rocky 9.3.Anybody has suggestion?

```
[root@rocky9 ~]# systemctl status httpd
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; preset: disabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-03-22 03:26:10 +0330; 19min ago
       Docs: man:httpd.service(8)
   Main PID: 11100 (httpd)
     Status: "Total requests: 7; Idle/Busy workers 100/0;Requests/sec: 0.00616; Bytes served/sec:  36 B/sec"
      Tasks: 213 (limit: 23102)
     Memory: 33.7M
        CPU: 2.390s
     CGroup: /system.slice/httpd.service
             ├─11100 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─11101 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─11102 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             ├─11103 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND
             └─11104 /usr/sbin/httpd -DFOREGROUND

Mar 22 03:26:09 rocky9 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Mar 22 03:26:10 rocky9 httpd[11100]: AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using fe80::a00>
Mar 22 03:26:10 rocky9 httpd[11100]: Server configured, listening on: port 80
Mar 22 03:26:10 rocky9 systemd[1]: Started The Apache HTTP Server.
[root@rocky9 ~]# rpm -qc httpd
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-brotli.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-systemd.conf
[root@rocky9 ~]# ls /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rocky9 (RHEL 9), the httpd.conf file comes from a different package:

```
% rpm -qf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
httpd-core-2.4.57-5.el9.x86_64

% rpm -qc httpd-core
/etc/httpd/conf.d/autoindex.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-base.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-dav.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-mpm.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-optional.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-proxy.conf
/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/01-cgi.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
/etc/httpd/conf/magic
/etc/logrotate.d/httpd
/etc/sysconfig/htcacheclean
```